# How to put multiple CSV dataset to fit the model in Keras?

Tags: numpy, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I want to use RNN in **Keras** to train the model to predict the movement trajectory.

I have multiple CSV files. Those have the same features(columns), but have different numbers(rows). Example of one file's shape is (1078, 8) and another file is (666, 8). Each file represents one trajectory.

Now, I can **only** put one CSV file to train the model.

How can I put those datasets to fit the model in Keras?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate data with numpy, for exam:

```
CSV1 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (666, 8))
CSV2 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1078, 8))
input_data = np.concatenate((CSV1,CSV2))
```

Comment: This way will become two dimensions. Because I need the input_shape(numbers, timestamps, features).

Have any way can become three dimensions like (2, None, 8)?